# Css opacity one two div with negative margin

Tags: css

https://jsfiddle.net/1zj71an3/1/

```
html:    
<div id="one">
aaaaaaaa
</div>
<div id="two">
bbbbbbbb
</div>
css:
#one{
  background-color:yellow;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

#two{
  background-color:blue;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

I would like to set opacity 0.5 to bigger div and leave smaller div opacity 1. The problem is that the smaller div what overlay bigger div is also affected.

Is there a way with css to stop this behaviour?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add:

```
  #one {
      position: relative;
      z-index: -1;
  }
```

or

```
z-index: 1;
```

to make other div above.

Comment: Great! position: relative was what I was missing. :)